# prioritize ngclick over nghref in <a> elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-href

**tl;dr**: How can I force angular to only execute the ngclick directive in an `<a>` element without emptying/removing the `href`?

My site has some custom behavior on some elements (modal opens, location bar updates, etc.) but for SEO indexing I *also* need it to be an `<a>` element with an `href` attribute containing a valid link.

Such as:

```
<a href="/{{item.url}}" ng-click="doCustomStuff(item)">some link</a>
```

However, angular also executes the `href` and the routing makes my custom `ng-click` logic useless.

Is there a way to invert this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should pass `$event` parameter to onclick function and execute `e.preventDefault()` method;

```
<a ng-click="clickHandler($event)" href="/home" >home</a>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.clickHandler = function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sKHST3GkRENtxptxr0mK?p=preview

Comment: how can i execute the ng-click and after that i execute href ?