# AngularJS | How to combine ng-dblclick and ng-routing on the same element?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my app I have `index.html` where there is `ng-view` directive. Inside that directive I add information from `main.html` as defalut - it's a table of names and links. By clicking a link the content of `ng-view` updates and information about the particular link from `link.html`appears. Please, see my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head> ... </head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>AngularJS</h1>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

My `main.js`:

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/main.html'
            })
            .when('/link/:id', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/circle.html',
                controller: 'linkCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            })
    })
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.obj = [
            {name: "aaa", link: "000"},
            {name: "bbb", link: "111"},
            {name: "ccc", link: "222"}
        ];
        $scope.clickFunc = function() {
            alert('Im doubleclicked');
        };
    })
    .controller('linkCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.id = $scope.obj[$routeParams.id];
    });
```

Here is my `main.html`:

```
<h2>Information</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Link</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="link in obj">
        <td>{{ link.name }}</td>
        <td><a href="#/link/{{ $index }}" ng-dblclick="clickFunc()">{{ link.link }}</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is `link.html`:

```
<p>Welcome to the new link {{ id }}</p>
<a href="#/">Back to home</a>
```

I also need to be able to double click the same link. The question is how to do that because adding `ng-dblclick` directive doesn't work. Is there any way to make it possible? 
I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164909/trying-to-resolve-ng-click-and-ng-href-on-the-same-anchor-element) a similar question but I didn't see the answer.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You want a click event and a double click event on the same element? The first event would always fire before the double click event is raised.

Comment: @DominicScanlan, I want to be able to double click on my *a* element but at the same time I want my routing to work as well. Of course, this is an example from my real project that was simplified for SO.  I don't need a separate single click on my element unless it routes to another link.